# Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to view details of a specific post or id. But it's throwing error.  N.B: I want to use `get()` not `first()`.

Error:

> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myBlog\resources\views\post\viewPost.blade.php)

**1. allPostView.blade.php**

```
a href="{{ URL::to('view/post/'.$row->id) }}"
```

**2. web.php**

```
Route::get('view/post/{id}','PostController@viewPost');
```

**3. PostControler.php** [View/Read post (details view of a specific post or )]

```
public function viewPost($id){
    $post=DB::table('posts')
    ->join('categories','posts.category_id','categories.id')
    ->select('posts.*','categories.name')
    ->where('posts.id',$id)
    ->get();

    //return response()->json($post);
    return view('post.viewPost', compact('post'));
}
```

**4. viewPost.blade.php** Final view page

```
Category name: {{ $post->name }}

{{ $post->title }}

img src="{{URL::to($post->image)}}" style="height: 200px; width:400px;"

{{ $post->details }}
```

5. But when I use `return response()->json($post);` it's giving me data as expected. Like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75zq6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method returns a Collection, which is an object wrapper for arrays in `Laravel`. Since you have a where clause on id, you want a single object and you can use `first()` instead.

```
$post = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('categories', 'posts.category_id', 'categories.id')
    ->select('posts.*', 'categories.name')
    ->where('posts.id', $id)
    ->first();
```

**Alternative solution**

Even thou your solution is very optimal, there is a more practical solutions for dealing with relationships include in `Laravel`.

Define your relationship.

```
class Post {
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Now eager load the category, before the query is executed.

```
$post = Post::with('category')->find($id);
```

In your view you can simply access the category name through the relationships, in a fairly optimal query execution plan. Meanwhile your code is way more readable and maintainable and in my opinion this is the correct `Laravel` way of doing this.

```
{{ $post->category->name }}
```